# Does Ubuntu suppport adding running GUI Applications to background with Hotkey?

Tags: background-process

I already know how to put an already running process into background from `command line`  but I was curious if there would be any chance to put a running `GUI` process into background using configurable `HotKey`.

Comment: You can stop a process with `ctrl z` and then make it run in the background with `bg`. If you wish you can make a hotkey for `bg` or for both operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> will place your focused program in the background. It will actually hide or minimize the window, so move it out of sight.

You can change that shortcut key in "Settings" - "Keyboard", "View and Customize Shortcuts", section "Windows".

Comment: nice to know, can I modify this shortcut key?

Comment: For sure you can change that shortcut in the Settings. Added the information.